# Not able to run command by Runtime.exec

Tags: java, macos, shell, unix

Below command I can run though terminal but when I am trying to execute it through java code its giving me 127 exit code.

```
sledge connect --cluster_id=<name> --namespace=<name> --password=<pass>
```

Java:

```
   try {
            String[] cmd = { "/bin/bash", "sledge connect --cluster_id=<name> --namespace=<name> --password=<pass>"};
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
            int po = p.waitFor();
            System.out.println(po);
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: You need a `-c` in there, or get rid of the shell. Always try your command strings in the command line before writing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to add "-c" in your commands array, so replace :

```
String[] cmd = { "/bin/bash", "sledge connect --cluster_id=<name> --namespace=<name> --password=<pass>"};
```

With :

```
String[] cmd = { "/bin/bash", "-c", "sledge connect --cluster_id=<name> --namespace=<name> --password=<pass>"};
```

From bash manual :

> -c string If the -c option is present, then commands are read from string.  If there are arguments after the string, they are assigned to
>   the  positional  parame‐
>                    ters, starting with $0.